# Build error domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405

Tags: xcode, react-native

I can build on my iOS 15 emulator with no problems, but when building on my iOS 15 Device connected to xcode 13. I get the error:

error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown.

Any ideas?

Console:

```
success Successfully built the app
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CECA2B5E-D9A0-4A52-8947-BF0838EBEDD6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4B8F148A-C39B-42B8-B982-82759A99BAF9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8853D49D-06EB-4542-AE09-EFD94DC045D6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1F7B80D0-0CFE-4D4F-AF69-260D8F0D785C, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7AF2F670-7D7B-4C0D-B1A2-DDD9A8DC0554, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5A36169B-4CE3-4E54-AC1D-8E2550EAAF61, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DA7C5083-DE28-40C8-83D3-7BA678311561, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C012CD47-9A6D-4B88-B209-4777EE57BD2A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C64ECA5-9EE0-4D2C-A0C9-82CAD36AE094, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DBA58C7D-41CB-44B2-99FA-F07E5CB829B5, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B43092DC-8F33-47BD-8429-A4D35C7FD7B8, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E587AD8C-D9B6-4683-9251-6D0F5DF50A57, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A7AC21A-A578-40A7-9C81-53B7F90CAED6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:352BE540-010B-4A15-B67D-965A884BB20D, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:24BBBFF1-FF95-453D-A952-66D3A93D611D, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:75F7457E-C581-4247-A1DC-E92CA319A693, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1482EAA0-8637-4D49-A091-B604208127BB, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:38D1E279-3D1E-4248-8B9D-76A3480D1CF0, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:54079569-B96E-4570-A076-732A2DED9E49, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A0CBCD90-C028-420B-9D6F-07E6EDA643FC, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E034D4B3-770E-4AD1-8573-DF7984340F16, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
info Installing "/Users/mattharris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myracnative-glxuojrfejxbhqgircpjgklctbto/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myracnative.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Delete Xcode cache

Delete Project Build and indexes

Path:>
about this Mac>Storage>Manage>Developer

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvUYl.png)

Comment: Then you might need to restart your machine first and then run the app.

Comment: To make it work I also needed to force quit the simulator.

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: I deleted both the Build and Indexes directory and the Xcode Cache directory and it worked but it took longer to launch the app in the simulator. I hope I didn't mess up

Comment: There is no `Developer` menu item in my version `10.14.6`.

Comment: This worked. The simctl erase had no impact.

Answer (score 98):

I got this error when the simulator is already open while I ran `react-native run-ios`. Closed the simulator all the way. Reran the command and it worked.

Comment: Work for me to! TNX!

Comment: Worked for me as well !!

Comment: Worked for me! thank you so much

Comment: Worked also for me. Thank you so much

Comment: worked for me! ty

Comment: This was the best answer for my case. Worked for me as well.

Comment: I closed the simulator and xcode

Comment: Killing simulator worked for me as well!

Answer (score 25):

Solutions:

1. Just `quit` the Simulator, and then run again `react-native run-ios`.
2. If, during the build, you get e.g. `info Launching iPhone 13 (iOS 15.5)` but the simulator does not open, do the following: Before the build is finished, right-click the simulator icon and go to `Device` and choose the device the build says it is going to build it on.

Comment: ⚠️⚠️ don't forget to use command+q to quit

Comment: I had ghost processes running on OS X. Go to Activity Monitor and force quit any "simulator" tasks. I also had to delete the XCode cache per @green's answer below.

Answer (score 25):

This instantly fixed the error for me:

1. Quit the simulator
2. Go to menu bar and click Apple icon > About this Mac > Storage > Storage Settings > Developer
3. Delete XCode Cache
4. Re-run `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 20):

To fix it, I ***simply*** select a specific iOS simulator and it runs successfully.

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"
```

Answer (score 12):

Please follow these steps:

```
Go to about this Mac -> Then Select Storage -> Select Manage -> Developer -> then Delete Project Build Data and Indexes.
```

It will work:

```
npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (9.7-inch)"
```

attaching a screenshot for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

do you run your code in an IDE?
I faced the same problem today after updating XCode.
If I run code in terminal I get other error: CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
Try this

```
sudo xcrun simctl shutdown all && sudo xcrun simctl erase all
```

More about https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/653807

Comment: this solution worked for me.

Comment: Been trying many of the solutions. Finally `sudo xcrun simctl shutdown all` and then `npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"` did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Try this Solution

1. Click the apple icon top left corner
2. Select `About this Mac`
3. Select `Storage` Click `Manage`
4. Select `Developer` on your left
5. Lastly delete `Build and indexes` just under `Xcode Project Build files`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the simulator still running in background (the icon was display in the dock with the white dot). I forced kill it and everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have another simulator somewhere in the background, that was my problem after all.

Answer (score 1):

Open `xcode` go to -> `preferences` -> `Locations`

and set `Relative` in `Derived Data`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Very weird behavior in my opinion, but I tried everything and I finally found the solution.

The problem was due to me changing my email address of my apple id.
Seems like the Simulator tries to use the apple id internally and thus - if it cannot connect - does not boot correctly.

After fixing the email address in `XCode` -> `Preferences` -> `Accounts` (i just added the new email address and removed the old one) everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the dot near the simulator (meaning it was active) but it did not open.
What helped me was doing:
Right click the simulator --> Device --> choose one.
that opened it.

Answer (score 0):

Even after deleting the Xcode cache, I still couldn't open the simulator.

For those who even don't know how to see the logs, here's how you can do so.

1. Open the Finder and go to your home file (it's the one with the home icon next to it in the sidebar where most of your stuff will most likely be stored).
2. Press `Cmd + Shift + .` to see the hidden files and open the 'Library' file.
3. Click on Logs -> Core Simulator -> CoreSimulator.log.

`~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimlator.log`

While in the 'Library' folder, navigate to the 'Core Simulator' folder where you'll see the 'Caches' folder.

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches`

Deleting this 'Caches' folder worked for me.

Here's [a helpful Medium article](https://medium.com/@liwp.stephen/my-solution-to-solve-unable-to-boot-the-ios-simulator-39bbb4aad100) on some other things to try should you still have problems.

It helped me out immensely.