# Failed to launch the app on simulator in react native

Tags: ios, react-native

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown

```
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
```

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312343/build-error-domain-com-apple-coresimulator-simerror-code-405

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build error domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312343/build-error-domain-com-apple-coresimulator-simerror-code-405)

Comment: @Naresh I tried all the stack overflow's answers but it is not opening the simulator, I need to close the simulator forcly either I have to open from Xcode, which is not right way for me