# An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=403):

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, react-hooks

I am getting this error as soon as I hit play on XCode

```
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=403):
Incompatible device
```

I tried this solution already here
[Build error domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312343/build-error-domain-com-apple-coresimulator-simerror-code-405)

Also things I have tried

1. reinstalling XCode by deleting all caches as well as XCode
2. recloning repo
3. cleaning build etc
4. Making sure the simulator is quit, by terminating the process and trying again
5. Restarting mac

Full log
https://gist.github.com/abdul-ahad-panelist/21a48667e3260c4b4b55a492dadb5ffa

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether iOS 17.2 runtime is installed or not(refer the attached image). If it is installed, make sure the device you are running the project on has the same runtime. If both of the things are right, then try

1. deleting the simulator and creating a fresh one
2. If above doesn't work then delete the existing runtime and redownload it and create a fresh simulator.

[image: runtime]